# Same xpath value appearing on different rows on a grid

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

For my automated test case, I need to traverse a grid to find a person that just registered so that I can perform necessary actions. I am trying to do so through xpath, but what I have noticed is that although there are more than 100 rows in the grid, It only returns 31 rows when I do the following:

```
List<WebElement> RowCount=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='grid']/div[5]/div/div/div[3]"));
System.out.println(RowCount.size());
```

The grid is loaded through the following:

```
<div class = "grid-widget">
        <div id = "grid" style="width:99%;height:700px;">Loading...</div>
        <div id="pager_grid" style="width:99%;height:20px;"></div>
    </div>
    <script>

        var grid_grid;
        var dataView_grid;
    </script>


    </div>
```

The html is:

```
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:0px">
<div class="slick-cell l0 r0">
<div class="slick-cell l1 r1" title="">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l2 r2 active" title="James010315075108">James010315075108</div>
<div class="slick-cell l3 r3">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l4 r4">12/04/1992</div>
<div class="slick-cell l5 r5">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l6 r6">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l7 r7">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l8 r8"></div>
<div class="slick-cell l9 r9">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l10 r10">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l11 r11"></div>
<div class="slick-cell l12 r12">test@test.com</div>
<div class="slick-cell l13 r13">Pending</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:25px">
<div class="slick-cell l0 r0">
<div class="slick-cell l1 r1">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l2 r2">David010415075207</div>
<div class="slick-cell l3 r3">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l4 r4">12/04/1992</div>
<div class="slick-cell l5 r5">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l6 r6">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l7 r7">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l8 r8"></div>
<div class="slick-cell l9 r9">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l10 r10">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l11 r11"></div>
<div class="slick-cell l12 r12">test@test.com</div>
<div class="slick-cell l13 r13">Pending</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:50px">
<div class="slick-cell l0 r0">
<div class="slick-cell l1 r1">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l2 r2">Roger010415081309</div>
<div class="slick-cell l3 r3">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l4 r4">12/04/1992</div>
<div class="slick-cell l5 r5">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l6 r6">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l7 r7">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l8 r8"></div>
<div class="slick-cell l9 r9">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l10 r10">test</div>
<div class="slick-cell l11 r11"></div>
<div class="slick-cell l12 r12">test@test.com</div>
<div class="slick-cell l13 r13">Pending</div>
```

When I listed the xpath of a particular column for about 15 rows, I saw that there were about 2-3 repetitions already.

How can I traverse the grid in this case? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying the webtable is not properly loaded and you want to wait for the table to be loaded completelyl?

Comment: The grid is loaded. Its not an issue of the grid not loading. The issue is there are more than 1 rows with the same xpath and that is causing some problems for me to get to a row i want to get to.

Comment: Then why do not you go by the class name since they are unique so far I see on the html? or is there a particular one you want?

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work either:
    List<WebElement> RowCount2=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' l2 ') and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' r2 ')]  ")));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get to the xpath I wanted to get to by doing the following:

```
By byXpath2 = By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'" + Name + "')]/../div/select[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' editor-select ')]");    
    WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(byXpath2);
    act.sendKeys(element2, "r").build().perform();
```

Thanks @Saifur for your help.

Comment: I am glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

- Seems like you are looking for a single person. So, I would not see
  the reason of using `List<T>`
- Sometimes this kind of Grid takes a while to load and for that reason you may need to implement some explicit wait(disregard this if
  not needed)
- Selenium does support compound class and I see the a significance compounding of class for the active user. You can use that. which can
  easily be used with `By byCss = By.cssSelector(".slick-cell.l2.r2.active");`css selector. However, I do not see the reason of depending on particular `div` since you are (probably) looking for the user with **active** class which can be done easily as follows. Note: I assume **active** class is being used only once in the grid and only for the active user you are looking for.

  ```
  By byCss = By.cssSelector(".active"); 
  WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byCss)); 
  //do whatever you need to do here
  ```

Comment: Hi Saifur, Thanks for your help so far. The active class was there only because i clicked on that cell, so during test run active will not be there. Each and every row has the same css class for the person's name column. I will need to click on the Pending field if I find the member. But as of now , unable to find the member.

Comment: @WebDriver How about the title attribute?

Comment: The title attribute is there for every row as well. The value is the same as name of the member.

Comment: Can you please replace the html with the actual one then?

Comment: @WebDriver So say the username is not present and do you click the pending to load more? And, is user is unique?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77663/discussion-between-webdriver-and-saifur).